# Javascript store array outside dynamic content and reuse if needed

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas

I'm experimenting with some html 5 canvas and at a certain point I tried to update the canvas with new bars (rectangles).

Now the tricky part.

Lets say you have an array with  1800 items(numbers generated by a php request).
You also have an html 5 canvas with the width of 1163px.

Now you need to draw bars(rectangles) in the canvas, but the bars need to remain 2px wide and there must be a 1px margin between all bars.

So the PHP file always returns 1800 numbers (color codes from image) and you need to extract just enough numbers to fit the canvas width(with the margin included(bar+margin)).

The new array of numbers you extract cannot just be the first 100-200 numbers! It must contain the (first or second) and (last or last-1) number.

What I have tried so far

```
<script>

// 1800 numbers !!! ......... //
arr = [12,1,21,1,2,13,21,32,1,5,4,6,5,4,6,4,8,3,5,4,9,6,8,7,9,1,3,6,4,6,4,5,9,87,4,4,5];

c = getElementById('canvas');
ctx = c.getContex('2d');

var can = 360;

var spliter = 2;

var canWidth = c.width;
var numOfBars = arr.length;
var barwidth = 2;
var margin = 1;

// amount of bars that will fit in the canvas //
var maxbars  = (canWidth / (barwidth + margin));

var offset = arr.length / maxbars;

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] % offset){
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.fillRect(
            this.margin + i * this.barwidth / numOfBars,
            0,
            barwidth + margin,
            100
          );
    }
}

</script>
```

This does not seem to work how I need it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maxbars must be an integer right? and same for offset.
After that offset is your step.

```
var maxbars  = Math.floor(canWidth / (barwidth + margin));
var offset = Math.floor(arr.length / maxbars);

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=offset) {
        var colorcode = arr[i];
        // fill stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me figure out a solution.